# Serial Communication with ASCII Commands in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ascii, pyserial

Hello guys I am attempting to write ASCII commands & in return read the serial buffer & get serial data. I am having an issue parsing the serial data out to only read the serial data I want to see and use.

**The Code:**

```
import serial

# Serial Connection
ser = serial.Serial(
        port="COM2", baudrate = 38400,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1)

# Write ASCII Commands To TSI 4043 Flow Sensor
ser.write(b'?\r\n') # Ask Sensor if it is getting a signal (Returns "OK")
ser.write(b'SUS\r\n') # Set Flow type to SLPM (Returns "OK")
ser.write(b'SG0\r\n') # Set Flow Gas to Air (Returns "OK")
ser.write(b'SSR0010\r\n') # Set Sample Rate to 10ms (Returns "OK")
ser.write(b'DAFxx0010\r\n') # Read 10 sensor Flow Reading

# Read ASCII From Serial Buffer
output = ser.read(100) # Read 100 bytes from serial buffer
print(output)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
b'OK\r\nOK\r\nOK\r\nOK\r\nOK\r\n80.63,80.42,80.52,80.32,80.33,80.66,79.88,80.39,80.26,80.28\r\n'
```

What I want to happen:

```
OK
OK
OK
OK
80.63,80.42,80.52,80.32,80.33,80.66,79.88,80.39,80.26,80.28
```

The OKs are just for debugging purposes. What I really need is to put all of the flow readings into an array so I can average it so I can watch the change in real time and control a motor.

Answer (score 0):

You should change Your approach a bit.
Read from serial port after every `ser.write` and parse / process it's `output`.
Check if You actually receive `b'OK\r\n'` response from the device and make sure You comply with Device communication protocol (what are possible outputs for every command You send). You never know when Device throw an error while processing the command.

Like this You will already have communication in a way **WRITE** `command` => **READ** `output` for every command You send.

Then it comes to the part of flow readout. You should have just `b'80.63,80.42,80.52,80.32,80.33,80.66,79.88,80.39,80.26,80.28\r\n'` in Your `output`.
You can process it and get average with:

```
# Output value from DAFxx0010 command
output = b'80.63,80.42,80.52,80.32,80.33,80.66,79.88,80.39,80.26,80.28\r\n'
# Decode bytes to string, remove `\r\n`, split by ',' and convert values to float and save them into list
output_values = [float(val) for val in output.decode().strip().split(",")]
# Average all values
output_avg = sum(output_values) / len(output_values)
```

Now You have clean communication with Device and Your script can handle possible communication errors.